# Django template - convert variable to list

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have array that I am passing to template include, example:

```
{% include 'chant_box.html' with chants=all_chants only %}
```

Sometimes I have only single chant and it doesn't make sense to pass it as array from view (apart from "practical" reasons). I would like to pass it to this template and I need to convert it to list first, something like:

```
{% include 'chant_box.html' with chants=[single_chant] only %}
```

But that doesn't work, wrapping in list() or make_list filter doesn't work either (makes list of letters of string representation). Is there standard way to do this? I know I can make custom filter, but I really don't want to do that unless I have to.

Comment: A singleton list makes lots of sense here, for exactly the 'practical reasons' that you cite... Why do you want to complicate things?

Comment: I also need the "single_chant" variable in the current template so having it wrapped in singleton list also complicates things.

Comment: You can add `single_chant` to your included template and pass it in as well, and wrap the `chants` and `single_chant` parts in `if chants` and `if single_chant` respectively

Comment: Yeah I could do that. Doesn't sound like really clean solution to add bunch of if's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating simple custom filter:

```
@register.filter(name='singleton_list')
def image_data(object):
    return [object]
```

Other pretty ok way to do it would be to use template inheritance to avoid conditions and too many duplicities.